# RealityKit – updateHandler of trackedRaycast not called

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, raycasting, realitykit

I call `trackedRaycast()` from `startTracing()` which is called from `viewDidLoad()`. My goal is to have the AR content be placed wherever the raycast from the camera hits a horizontal surface and that it updates when the raycast intersects a different location. When the user taps the screen the updates stop.
The updateHandler closure of the function trackedRaycast is never executed.

```
import RealityKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    var gameAnchor: Experience.PreviewBoard!
    var raycast: ARTrackedRaycast?
    var gameIsPlaced = false
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupARConfiguration()
        loadGameBoard()
        startTracing()
        
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(recognizer:)))
        arView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }
    
    func setupARConfiguration() {
        arView.automaticallyConfigureSession = false
        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        config.planeDetection = [.horizontal]
        config.isCollaborationEnabled = true
        config.environmentTexturing = .automatic
        arView.session.run(config)
    }
    
    func loadGameBoard() {
        gameAnchor = try! Experience.loadPreviewBoard()
        arView.scene.addAnchor(gameAnchor)
    }
    
    func startTracing() {
        raycast = arView.trackedRaycast(from: view.center, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .horizontal) { results in
            print("This is never executed")
            // Refine the game position with raycast update
            if let result = results.first {
                self.gameAnchor.setTransformMatrix(result.worldTransform, relativeTo: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func stopTracing() {
        print("raycast has stopped")
        raycast?.stopTracking()
    }
    
    @objc func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if !gameIsPlaced {
            gameIsPlaced = true
            stopTracing()
        }
    }
}
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be some kind of lag when the view is initialized, leading to the tracked raycast not being initialized from the usual lifecycle methods. When I tried initializing it via a tap on the screen, it worked as intended. You can check this with the following code:

```
    var r : ARTrackedRaycast? {
        didSet {
            print("Raycast initialized")
        }
    }
    
    r = self.arView.trackedRaycast(from: self.view.center, allowing: .existingPlaneInfinite, alignment: .any) { result in
        print("Callback received")
    }
```

If you initialize your raycast from `viewDidLoad()` or `viewDidAppear()` even, the setter is never called.

The solution for me was to delay the raycast's initialization by a few seconds, like so:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
        r = self.arView.trackedRaycast(from: self.view.center, allowing: .existingPlaneInfinite, alignment: .any) { result in
            print("Callback received")
    }
```

This is, obviously, far from ideal, but right now I'm not sure how to go about solving that issue any differently.